# Can I use hashing(#) and non hashing(#) routing both in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I want to use hashing(#) for some routes and some routes without hashing(#). How can I implement this, e.g want to load **attendance-report** path with hashing and non-hashing both. Here is my app.module.ts file

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthGaurdService } from "./auth/auth-gaurd/auth-gaurd.service";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./dashboard/pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.component";
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "attendance-report/:token",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./dashboard/pages/agent-attendance/agent-attendance.module").then(
        (m) => m.AgentAttendanceModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: "",
    canActivate: [AuthGaurdService],
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
      {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./dashboard/dashboard-layout.module").then(
            (m) => m.AdminLayoutModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      relativeLinkResolution: "legacy",
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Could you share a context of how you would be using both the hashing and non hashing methods?

Answer (score 0):

Docs: [Setting and handling query params and fragments](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#setting-and-handling-query-params-and-fragments)

The following link adds a query parameter and a fragment to the generated URL:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}" fragment="education">
  link to user component
</a>
```

By default, the directive constructs the new URL using the given query parameters. The example generates the link: `/user/bob?debug=true#education`.

You can instruct the directive to handle query parameters differently by specifying the `queryParamsHandling` option in the link. Allowed values are:

`'merge'`: Merge the given `queryParams` into the current query params.
`'preserve'`: Preserve the current query params.
For example:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}" queryParamsHandling="merge">
  link to user component
</a>
```

See [UrlCreationOptions#queryParamsHandling.](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlCreationOptions#queryParamsHandling)

Comment: But I want to  **http://localhost:4200/attendance-report:token**  path with hashing and non-hashing route both  e.g i can access **http://localhost:4200/attendance-report:token**,**http://localhost:4200/#/attendance-report:token**   routes both